# Setting left inset of empty uitableviewcells (placeholder cells) to 0 to eliminate left padding?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I was able to find an answer in stack overflow that led me to successfully eliminate the default left padding occurring on my cell separator by setting left inset = 0 in the storyboard of Xcode.  However the empty cells beneath my populated custom cells still have padding on their left separators.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard for the Table, Set the separator inset

[image]

And finally in `awakeFromNib` for custom table cell

> **Swift 3.x**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
}
```

> **For Swift 2.x**

```
self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You haven't posted any code. Who can see the problem without a code